# How to pass a foreign key id from query to the updating row element?

Tags: scala, slick, for-comprehension

I'm using Slick 3.3.0 and I have a use-case for updating a password table but the look up element is something called a `LoginInfo` which then links to the target updateable `PasswordInfo` via its `user_id` this is a very simplified version of my use case:

```
def update(id: Long, hasher: String, password: String, salt: Option[String]): Future[ExtPasswordInfo] = {
    // first look up a loginInfo by some id, then find the connected userId and use 
    // it to update the PasswordInfo.
    val action = (for {
      loginInfo <- LoginInfo if loginInfo.id === id
      passwordInfo <- PasswordInfo if passwordInfo.userId === loginInfo.userId
    } yield passwordInfo).update(PasswordInfoRow(??? /* <<<< I need userId here */, hasher, password, salt))
    db.run(action)
}
```

But after the query yields `passwordInfo` and I chain the `update` method I have no access to the `userId` key.

If were possible I'd need:

```
... yield passwordInfo).update(pi => PasswordInfoRow(pi.userId, ...
```

How do do this in Slick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some soul searching I solved it like this:

```
def update(id: Long, hasher: String, password: String, salt: Option[String]): Future[ExtPasswordInfo] = {
    // first look up a loginInfo by some id, then find the connected userId and use 
    // it to update the PasswordInfo.
    val action = (for {
      userId <- LoginInfo.filter(_.id === id).result.head.map(_.userId)
    } yield userId).flatMap { userId =>
      val updated = PasswordInfoRow(userId, hasher, password, salt)
      PasswordInfo.update(updated).map(_ => updated.toExt)
    }.transactionally()
    db.run(action)
}
```